# read .yml files in matlab issue

Tags: matlab, file-io, yaml

For my project I want to read yml file in matlab using [YAMLMatlab](https://code.google.com/p/yamlmatlab/). My .yml files look like this. I am ust showing a part of .yml file. My file is around 29 MB.

```
%YAML:1.0
Block size: [ 16, 16 ]
Block stride: [ 8, 8 ]
Cell size: [ 8, 8 ]
block hist size: 36
block per img: [ 63, 63 ]
Total elements in array: 142884
nbins: 9
Scale: 1.
Level: 0
Width: 512
Height: 512
features:
   - 1.5302167832851410e-01
   - 1.0552208870649338e-01
   - 1.6659785807132721e-01
   - 2.3539969325065613e-01
   - 2.0810306072235107e-01
   - 1.2627227604389191e-01
   - 8.0759152770042419e-02
   - 6.4930714666843414e-02
   - 6.1364557594060898e-02
   - 2.1614919602870941e-01
   - 1.4714729785919189e-01
```

While reading .yml file I got the following error.

```
Error using ReadYamlRaw>load_yaml (line 78)
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.<init>(StreamReader.java:51)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:399)

Error in ReadYamlRaw (line 42)
    result = load_yaml(filename, nosuchfileaction, treatasdata);


Error in ReadYaml (line 48)
    ry = ReadYamlRaw(filename, 0, nosuchfileaction, treatasdata);


Error in untitled (line 2)
 YamlStruct = ReadYaml(yaml_file);
```

I believe this error is due to large file size as I can read simple .yml file. Can someone help me to resolve this error. I have also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017298/read-yml-files-in-matlab).

P.S: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/95yrfwee84dgh3m/Feature000000?dl=0) is .yml file

**EDIT:**
It works with below answer but I got the following error now. Once I remover `%YAML:1.0`. It works fine.

```
Error using ReadYamlRaw>load_yaml (line 78)
Java exception occurred:
while scanning a directive
 in "<string>", line 1, column 1:
    %YAML:1.0
    ^
expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found :(58)
 in "<string>", line 1, column 6:
    %YAML:1.0
         ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.scanDirectiveName(ScannerImpl.java:1028)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.scanDirective(ScannerImpl.java:990)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchDirective(ScannerImpl.java:534)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:251)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:179)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseImplicitDocumentStart.produce(ParserImpl.java:198)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:161)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:146)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:105)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:121)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:480)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:399)

Error in ReadYamlRaw (line 42)
    result = load_yaml(filename, nosuchfileaction, treatasdata);


Error in ReadYaml (line 48)
    ry = ReadYamlRaw(filename, 0, nosuchfileaction, treatasdata);


Error in untitled (line 2)
 YamlStruct = ReadYaml(yaml_file);
```

Answer (score 3):

In MATLAB, select Preferences from the menu/toolstrip. Find the section MATLAB>General>Java Heap Memory, and increase the Java heap size.

You'll need to restart MATLAB after changing this setting for it to take effect.

Comment: It works but I had new error. I edited my question. @Sam

Comment: I'm not a YAML expert, but I believe it's meant to be `%YAML 1.0`, rather than `%YAML:1.0`. Putting a colon in there makes the YAML invalid, and I think removing it should solve the problem (of course, stripping out the whole line as you tried should also do it).

Comment: actually it is automatically generated when I make ymle file in OpenCV and I have around 8000 yml files. So I need to read it like that.

Comment: I looked it up, and the YAML spec [says](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id895217)  that version directives (and all directives) have to be space-separated. So if OpenCV is producing colon-separated directives, I'd take that up with them. In the meantime, YAMLMATLAB does the actual reading of YAML using the SnakeYaml Java library, so to change the behaviour to recognise (bad) colon-separated directives, you'll need to get the Java source, modify it and rebuild the library. It might be easier to just find and replace in all your files :(

Comment: yeah that's what I am thinking.Thanks!