# YAML compatibility issue

Tags: matlab, opencv, yaml

For my project I had created 10,000 [YAML](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html) files using OpenCV.  Then I had to read those 10,000 files in MATLAB so I used [YAMLMATLAB](https://code.google.com/p/yamlmatlab/). Files created by OpenCV has the following code placed at the start of the each file.

```
%YAML:1.0
```

Unfortunately, YAMLMATLAB doesn't understand `%YAML:1.0`. Someone recommend me to rebuild YAMLMATLAB i.e. SnakeYaml Java library. Is there any other way around to make it work.

Comment: I suggest to take a reference here first, and if you still cannot solve it, then update your question with more detailed code:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017298/read-yml-files-in-matlab

Comment: as I have 10,000 files It will take too long to manually comment `%YAML:1.0`

Answer (score 0):

The `%` introduces a directive, and the `%YAML` [directive](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2781553), should be followed by a space to end the name if it was to be a recognisable directive (there are only two: `%TAG` and `%YAML`. This is actually a directive that is unknown with a value `%YAML:1.1` without any parameters.

MatLab (and e.g. PyYAML) refuse to load such a file, which IMO is not correct behaviour, as the YAML spec says to [ignore unknown directives](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2781147). Of course it is not nice that OpenCV provides an incorrect directive either.

Ignoring the incorrect directive is what [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) does (disclaimer: I am the author of that package). If you install that and run its utility `yaml` in roundtrip mode:

```
yaml rt --save *.yaml
```

files of the form:

```
%YAML:1.0
---
abc: def
klm: ghi
```

are converted to:

```
abc: def
klm: ghi
```

which should be loadable in MatLab.

**Make sure to make a backup of the files before running the command**, as the `--save` saves the files in place (i.e. overwrites the original).

If you don't want to install ruamel.yaml, you can of course also use some other commandline tool to remove the first two (directive and document separator) lines.